# Python - Spyder: no such file or directory

Tags: python

I have a file on my local machine with a path D://python/tex1.txt, but when i run the code

```
file_1 = open('D:/python/test1.txt','r')
```

in spyder environment it reports an error "No such file or directory". Just substituting the slashes with \ did not give result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: forward-slashes work fine on Windows as well. Are you absolutely sure the file exists? btw. this is not related to your IDE; removed tag "spyder".

Comment: os.listdir():  see the list of files in the current working directory. os.getcwd(): see whether you're in the directory you think you're in .